# What things from WWDC can we ask about here?

Tags: discussion

With the [annual developer conference WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/schedule/#/) starting today for 2016 - Apple is announcing new things.

Where can we ask / talk / learn more about the live stream of WWDC 2016 on Ask Different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are iOS 10, macOS 10.12, watchOS 3 or tvOS 10 (beta) questions OK?](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-10-macos-10-12-watchos-3-or-tvos-10-beta-questions-ok)

Comment: @Mark No - this was a required post to announce chat during WWDC. The linked question is specifically about asking a main site question. This is about use of chat rooms for gathering and discussing a live stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that isn't covered by the NDA, that's public knowledge, can be asked about on Ask Different.

[Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) is available for things that don't work as practical questions. Chat is also the best place to discuss the live stream since that part of community doesn't work well as practical Q/A on the main site.

Comment: Note that many people who have agreed to the NDA believe they can't respond and so the knowledge of the answers will be less than usual

Answer (score 0):

However is it worth answering anything here. In general we don't know at it is liable to change.

It would be much easier to simply say we don't know and close it.

e.g this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242601/cannot-use-icloud-photo-library-wrong-disk-format) and we get comments that are based on partial information

It is just wasting time to read let alone answer.

Also in a beta expect to have to reformat your disk. If you have to ask how to get data back you should not run a beta. So really any more questions on this is lack of research which is a reason to down vote